# $.Deferred() can't get 401 code

Tags: jquery, reactjs

The front end that I use is react. This back end that I use is springboot. Now I access the JWT. Having logged in, the user can get a token. Every backend request will take the token. Once the token expired or been tampered with, the backend will respond with a 401 HTTP code.

My goal is when the HTTP request responds with 401, jump to the login page. However I tried `error` or `done()` and they don't work. I always get:

```
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

How do I do to get the 401 status?

```js
const defer = $.Deferred()

$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: url,
    data: body,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", getToken());
    },
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    crossDomain: true,
    //error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //  console.log(textStatus,errorThrown)                               
    //  console.log(console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest))); 
    //  hashHistory.push("/login");
    //}
  }).done(defer.resolve).fail(function(res) {
    errHandler(JSON.stringify(res))
  });

return defer.promise()
```

Comment: If `status` is `0` it normally means that your AJAX request has not been sent, usually due to an issue with the data being sent but there can be other causes. Have you debugged the logic flow of the call?

Comment: Google browser has print "'Access - Control - Allow - Origin' header is present on the requested resource" and "The response had HTTP status code 401".if I don't use $.Deferred ,I can get 401.Once I use $.Deferred ,I can't get 401 in the error and fail.